# Strip all nulls from JSON string with regex

Tags: json, regex, string, apex

Given any valid string, is there a reliable regex or algorithm to remove all properties that are set to null?

```
{
  "prop1":"value1",
  "prop2":null,
  "prop3": "value2",
  "prop4":null
}
```

Assume that deserialization/serialization libraries cannot be used.  Also JSON is minified and there is no whitespace.

So far I have the follow:

```
public String replaceNulls(String json){
   json = json.replaceAll("(\"[\w]*\":null,)|(,?\"[\w]*\":null)",""); //regex replace all method
   return json;
}
```

But I'm not sure it covers all cases.  Even if it does, I have a feeling there might be a more optimized way of doing it.

Comment: Can you not use a parser for this?

Comment: @hwnd nope... its a long explanation, but I'm using a language (apex) that has very limited support for serialization.   I can serialize from an object, but all the null fields get output in the json string.  The API I'm calling rejects them as invalid.

Comment: sorry, technically there is a parser:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm#apex_System_JsonParser_methods  

I'd really like to use round trip serialization/de-serialization if possible.  Maybe I could use the parser to sanitize the string after serialization from an object.  Doesn't seem like it would be any easier of an approach though

Comment: I think this regex is better: `"\w+?"\s*:\s*null,?`

Comment: @PradeepKumar results in the following: `{"prop1":"value1","prop3": "value2",}`.  It leaves a trailing "," for some inputs.

Comment: I missed reading that your JSON is minified, so don't need that \s* in regex. So it should finally become `"\w+?":null,?`. I would just put a second replace immediately following this to replace `",}` with `"}`.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll have to do some benchmarking to see if running 2 simple replaces is more/less CPU intensive than a single one that is more complex.

Comment: Yes, first one would be regex replace and the second one would be a simple string replace. I'm not sure what the benchmarking results would be but string replace is much more efficient than regex in general. Plus it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: If this is Java please add a language tag.

Comment: You can try `json.replaceAll("(,?)\s*\"[^\"]*\":null,?|,(})","$1$2");`.

Comment: so.. seems like there are lots of options.  If someone wants to submit an answer and explain why they think it's the best one then I can give you guys credit

Comment: @NSjonas: if any works for you please let us know.

Comment: @stribizhev Pradeeps solution works (although I'm not sure it's actually faster).  I don't think that the language I'm using supports the syntax you provided for the replacement.

Comment: The Apex regex is in fact Java regex. Try `json.replaceAll("(,?)\\s*\"[^\"]*\":null,?|,(})","$1$2");` - I forgot to double escape `\\s`.

Comment: @stribizhev Apex uses ' for string literals instead of " so I modified it a bit: `json.replaceAll('(,?)\\s*\"[^\"]*\":null,?|,(})','$1$2');`.  Unfortunately, it's still not working as expected.  Can you explain the replacement regex: `'$1$2'`?  I'm pretty lousy at regex

Comment: `$1`and `$2` are backreferences to captured groups, those with parentheses `(...)`. I do not think the regex can help much since there are cases like the one at [`json.org/example`](http://json.org/example), and the null values inside `[...]` can hardly be handled correctly with Java-like regex. I will refrain from posting any suggestion as an answer.